# How to get full size image use browser on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I uploaded picture on iphone browser to my server, but the picture size and the original file is different, how to get the original size?

I select the file use  ,upload file size on android, desktop PC  is the same, in addition to iOS outside..Orz

---

My source file put to https://github.com/mosutw/upload_image_ios
1.My orginal image file is gtMi_orginal.jpg(15890Bytes),it include some infomation behind the image format.
2.I send email with file and save in the iphone(gtMi_save_from_image.jpg).but the file size is 26191Bytes,although the file size is changed, but additional information still exist.
3.I upload the file(gtMi_save_from_image.jpg) to webserver(savetohtml.html).I check the uploaded file only 3294 bytes and my information has missing.

How can I send the file to web server and keep my information?

Comment: How are you uploading the file exactly?

Comment: We're going to need some more information and code samples if we're to have any hope of helping you.

Comment: I has update information, thank you for help.

Comment: I use Browser in iphone, like this https://jsfiddle.net/mosutw/vrygep8y/1/ 
 when I select the file ,the file size different original(but android, desktop PC is correct)